# Faster redirect, PHP or htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

What is FASTER way to redirect a particular (specific) page, a PHP or htaccess? Considering that many different pages may need such redirect on a high traffic site. e.g. what is faster:

PHP (no database queries involved, just simple plain php redirect)

```
header("Location: /new.php",TRUE,301);
```

or

htaccess

```
redirect 301 old.php http://site.com/new.php
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depends. In general, .htaccess will be faster because you won't have the overhead of invoking PHP. However -- if you've got 1000 redirects in a single .htaccess file at the document root level, then Apache will need to check every one of them on every page load. I.e., instead of just serving index.php, you're now going to have to do 1000 regex checks, and *then* serve index.php. Overall, I'd say that if you've got a lot of redirects *and* a lot of pages that won't be redirected, then do it in PHP. In this case, you don't pay any extra overhead for the pages that don't need to be redirected.

Answer (score 7):

`.htacess` are processed before php is called, so if you can create it, it will surely be faster

Comment: However. .htaccess itself is loaded/parsed for each hit, so perhaps PHP can be faster in some circumstances (very complex .htaccess for one), particularly with caches in place.

Comment: if there is a complex .htaccess, it will be parsed anyway and added to the time to proccess the PHP, so there is no gain there either

Answer (score 3):

If `.htaccess` is used at all, Apache will process it before any PHP processing begins. I haven't done the benchmarks on using one or the other, but when both are present, `.htaccess` will always be faster.

Also note that `.htaccess` redirect can be written using regex to apply to multiple old files, so less work on your end.

Comment: htaccess will always be faster... yes, but only for the pages who had an interest to go trough the htacess; if 99% of your pages are not redirected, but yet you have 1 000 lines in your .htaccess : then parsing the .htaccess for EVERY request is slowing down more that the 1% of pages who benefit of not going though php to be redirected